# Unable to grab classes using Selenium in TripAdvisor

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape all of the images for a specific TripAdivsor page but when using the find_elements_by_class_name function in Selenium, it is giving me no values whatsoever. I am confused as that is the exact class name for what values I want to iterate through and append to a list, here is the [site](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g28970-d84078-Reviews-Hyatt_Regency_Washington_on_Capitol_Hill-Washington_DC_District_of_Columbia.html#/media/84078/405571061:p/?albumid=101&type=2&category=101). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
# importing dependencies
import re
import selenium
import io
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from _datetime import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


#setup opening url window of website to be scraped
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless=False
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2} 
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/rishi/Downloads/chromedriver 3") #possible issue by not including the file extension
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)
driver.get("""https://www.tripadvisor.com/""") #get the information from the page

#automate searching for hotels in specific city
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[6]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/span[1]/div/div/div/a').click() #clicks on hotels option
driver.implicitly_wait(12) #allows xpath to be found
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="BODY_BLOCK_JQUERY_REFLOW"]/div[12]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/input').send_keys("Washington D.C.", Keys.ENTER) #change string to get certain city
time.sleep(8)

#now get current url
url = driver.current_url

response = requests.get(url)
response = response.text
data = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')

#get list of all hotels
hotels = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("prw_rup prw_meta_hsx_responsive_listing ui_section listItem")

print("Total Number of Hotels: ", len(hotels))
```

Comment: I checked page in web browser  and I can't find this class on page - maybe it uses different names in every request or for different users. Besides page uses JavaScript to add elements but BeautifulSoup can't run JavaScript and you may need Selenium to control web browser which can run JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that, if you use Selenium, don't use BeautifulSoup beside it because you can get whatever you want using Selenium.

You can simply achieve your goal as follows:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/rishi/Downloads/chromedriver 3")
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.ca/Hotels")

time.sleep(1)

driver.implicitly_wait(12)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="typeahead_input"]').send_keys("Washington D.C.", Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(1)
hotels = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="listing collapsed"]')

print("Total Number of Hotels: ", len(hotels))
```

Please note that using this code you would get the first 30 hotels (i.e., first page). You would need to loop through all the pages of hotels of the specified city in order to get them all.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just have one quick question about that code, how did you get that xpath? I tried to go the the div where you found it but when I tried to copy it, it did not give me the same result.

Comment: Great! You can actually get any details of HTML tags or class names in a Web page using the "Developers Tools". You can find it in the Browser menu, or using "CTRL+SHIFT+i" on Google Chrome, or using "F12" using Microsoft Edge.

Comment: I tried doing so and going to the div that contained "<div class="listing collapsed"" and I copied that xpath, but it gave me the result of: //*[@id="taplc_hsx_hotel_list_lite_dusty_hotels_combined_sponsored_0"]/div[2]/div

Comment: I see. Just pick the class name and use it for finding elements in your code. You don't need all such detailed xpath.